# @Input com Observable no angular

Tags: angular, typescript, front-end

Não tenho um erro ainda, mas não sei como fazer...

Tenho uma toolbar no meu AppComponent, que exibe um menu dropdown com uma lista. Essa lista vem do back-end. Preciso de um Observable que recebe um boolean, pois se for true recebo uma lista e false outra lista.

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<mat-toolbar>
    <a target="_blank" class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.nrisklog.com.br/">
        <img src="./assets/nrisk-logo.svg" alt="" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
    </a>
    <button class="buttonMenu" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuIntegradores">Integradores</button>
    <mat-menu #menuIntegradores="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let integrador of integradores"
            (click)="moreInformations(integradores.indexOf(integrador))">{{integrador.tecnologia}}</button>
    </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

A váriavel boolean foi declarada em outro component **components/integrador.ts**,que é onde é feita a requisição da lista ao back-end

Answer (score 0):

Ficou a dúvida se o problema é na chamada da api ou no tratamento da resposta.
Pela forma que escreveu parece que uma condicional ngif já resolve.

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock"> Lista true</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>lista false.</ng-template>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).